# Windows Workflow Foundation - Activity Designer - How to check variables/arguments at run time?

Tags: .net, debugging, workflow-foundation-4

I'm debugging a workflow using the WF4 activity designer. Using the designer for debugging, how can I access the workflow instance state at run time to check variable values?

For instance, how can I check the value of bool softwareFlashRequired in the following screen:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created a CodeActivity that takes in the variable and then has a break point within it.  You can use a PreProcessor to turn the break point on and off. For example: `#if DEBUG`

I put the activity into the workflow before the condition.

For ease of use in workflows I place all variables inside a container so my Debug CodeActivity only has to have one InArgument and at the break point you can see the state of all of them.